# Could not view the pdf file in the child window

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-viewer

I have below code in **Parent** window.

```
private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Help helpWindow=new Help();
    helpWindow.MdiParent = this;
    helpWindow.BringToFront();
    helpWindow.Show();        
}
```

**Child** window code is below.

```
public Help()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"D:\sample.pdf");
}
```

If I use above code, I could not view the pdf in my child window. But if I remove the below code `helpWindow.MdiParent = this;`
from the parent window, I am able to view the pdf but it is opening in a separate window which is not my requirment.

Comment: Have you tried `yourForm.IsMdiContainer = true;`?

Comment: yes i have tried this.IsMdiContainer = true; but i can not able to view the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your Help window is just being hidden by other controls on the parent `Form`? Perhaps a `Panel` that has a `DockStyle` of `Fill`? I don't believe `BringToFront()` overrides the foreground controls of the parent `Form`.

From the given information it would seem that the code for your PDF viewing form is fine, it just depends on what you mean by *"I could not view the pdf in my child window."*

Anyway, you could do something like this to see your child window is just being hidden:

```
private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
     {
          if (!(ctrl is MdiClient))
              ctrl.Hide();                                 
     }

     Help helpWindow=new Help();
     helpWindow.MdiParent = this;
     helpWindow.FormClosing += helpWindow_FormClosing;
     helpWindow.BringToFront();
     helpWindow.Show(); 
}

private void helpWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to your problem as I had been trying to resolve the same issue. The trick is to create a form specifically for showing the pdf file in the acrobat viewer and then adding that form to the MDI Child form. Then, when you want to show the selected pdf file, pass the file name to the child form and then pass that file name to the form that was added to the child form.
So you would declare a class level variable for the pdf form as below in your child form:

```
    frmPDF pdfForm = new frmPDF();
```

Create a method in your child that will accept the name of the pdf file as below and at the same time create an instance of the pdf form and add it to the mdi child form:

```
    public void LoadPDF(string fileName)
    {
        pdfForm.TopLevel = false;
        pdfForm.Parent = this;
        pdfForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        pdfForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pdfForm.Show();
        pdfForm.LoadPDF(fileName);
    }
```

And then, in your pdf form create the following method which will be called after the form is shown:

```
    public void LoadPDF(string fileName)
    {
        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@fileName);
    }
```

This should resolve the problem you have been having and allow you to have your help file display in a child window.

Hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up to my last answer, there are two things that are important for this solution to work:

1. The form the is being used for the `pdf` form must be added as:

   ```
   TopLevel = false;
   ```
2. The `pdf` form must complete the loading prior to the pdf file being loaded to the acrobat control. So if the child form is not already loaded and is being loaded in one step, it will only work if the code for loading the file in the form_shown event. The below shows a better implementation of the above solution.

   ```
   private string _pdfFileName = "";
   public string PDFFileName { set { _pdfFileName = value; } }

   private void frmPDF_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(_pdfFileName);
   }
   ```

The file name should then be set using the public property as seen below:

```
 pdfForm.PDFFileName=pdfFile;
```